# Save Instance Nested Serializers in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have problem with saving instance **Live_In** Nested Serializers in Django Rest Framework. Hope your guys help me! I think just a basic issue.

**My Serializers:**

I think it comes error when I write saving instance

```
class CityLiveInSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    country = CharField(required=False, source='country.name')
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = [
            'name',
            'slug',
            'country'
        ]    

class UserEditSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    live_in = CityLiveInSerializer(source='profile.live_in')
    about = serializers.CharField(source='profile.about')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'live_in',
            'about',
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.save()
        # Update Serializers Profile
        if (validated_data.get('profile') is not None):
            profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
            profile = instance.profile
            profile.about = profile_data.get('about', profile.about)
            profile.save()

        if (validated_data.get('live_in') is not None):
          live_in_data = validated_data.pop('live_in')
          try:
              city = City.objects.get(name=live_in_data['name'])
          except City.DoesNotExist:   
              city = City.objects.create(**live_in_data)
          instance.profile.live_in = city
          instance.profile.save()
        return instance
```

**My City Model (Live_in)**

```
class City(BaseCity):
    class Meta(BaseCity.Meta):
        swappable = swapper.swappable_setting('cities', 'City')

class BaseCity(Place, SlugModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="standard name")
    country = models.ForeignKey(swapper.get_model_name('cities', 'Country'), related_name='cities', null=True, blank=True)
```

**My Profile Model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # Extend User
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    live_in = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True, related_name="live_in")
```

Data sent by Postman (Json)

```
{ "live_in": { "name": "Encamp" } }
```

**TraceError:**

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  263.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  488.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  463.             raise type(exc)(msg)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/v1/users/account/edit/
Exception Value: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `live_in` on serializer `UserEditSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'live_in'.

Comment: Can you add user and profile models?

Comment: It's you again ^^. Added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you dont need `many=True` in this case. It required for related objects list, but you will pass only one city.
Secondly `live_in` is attribute of profile model so you need to update profile and add source argument:

```
live_in = CityLiveInSerializer(source="profile.live_in")

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
    instance.save()
    # Update Serializers Profile
    if (validated_data.get('profile') is not None):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        profile = instance.profile
        profile.about = profile_data.get('about', profile.about)
        if (profile_data.get('live_in') is not None):
            live_in_data = profile_data.pop('live_in')
            try:
                city = City.objects.get(name=live_in_data["name"])
            except City.DoesNotExist:   
                city = City.objects.create(**live_in_data)
        profile.live_in = city 
        profile.save()

    return instance
```

In this case you need to allow create city without country, so you need to add null=True, blank=True to country attribute:

```
class BaseCity(Place, SlugModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name="standard name")
    country = models.ForeignKey(swapper.get_model_name('cities', 'Country'),
                            related_name='cities', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: `null=True, blank=True` for Country will fix it but how if I want to data response have Country Data?

Comment: @FeedGit in this case you need to add one more level to you data: `{ "live_in": { "name": "Encamp",  "country": {"name": "CountryName"} }`. This mean you need to create another serializer CountrySerializer and add it to CityLiveInSerializer. Also you need to override CityLiveInSerializer's create and update methods like you did in UserEditSerializer. P.S. Yep it's me, hello again:)

Comment: Please take a look in my new code above with Traceback!

Comment: @FeedGit or you can allow users only to use existing in DB countries. In this case you dont need nested relation. Users can only send country id: `{ "live_in": { "name": "Encamp", "country": "1"}`

Comment: @FeedGit I think it should be `live_in = CityLiveInSerializer(source="profile.live_in')` Check updates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163138/discussion-between-neverwalkaloner-and-feed-git).